# ASP.Net Reportviewer in folder not working

Tags: asp.net, client, reportviewer, report

We can run the ReportViewer in a ASP.Net Web App project that is off the root OK so localhost/test/report.aspx works.  It's running as a Client Report. But if we move the application up another level the report stops working so localhost/testfolder/test/test.aspx.

When the report fails it has no data to display and none of the images are loading.

Info: We are bind the report in code and sort out the Report.LocalReport.ReportPath to the correct path.

Can't help thinking there is a setting wrong, but stumped at the moment!

From the comment I've probably not made my self clear, the ASP.Net WebApp is not at the root level it's at the.  There is the root application, then "testfolder" as an application and then "test".  There are no access permission problems for the files.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please give proper access permissions to new folder. I guess there would be report viewer user/group to give permission.